# Prb with inline validator yii2

Tags: yii2

I have written my own rule which must validate an array:

```
public function arrayValidation($attribute, $params)
{
    (is_array($this -> $attribute)
        && isset($params['min']) ? count($this -> $attribute) >= $params['min'] : true
        && isset($params['max']) ? count($this -> $attribute) <= $params['max'] : true)

    ? NULL : $this -> addError($attribute, "$attribute must be array.");
}
```

and use it on the rules function:

```
 ['hashtags', 'arrayValidation', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 3],
```

but yii2 complain of

> Unknown Property – yii\base\UnknownPropertyException

Setting unknown property: yii\validators\InlineValidator::min

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change your code like below:

```
['hashtags', 'arrayValidation','params'=>['min' => 0, 'max' => 3]],
```

In order to pass `params` to a custom validator, you should write it like above.